# permutation computing in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

I want to write a program that gets an integer n and prints all the permutations of 1,2,...,n.
I know there is a recursive way to do this and I know the overhead of function calls.
Is there any way to do this without recursion??

Comment: If you calculate something and print the immediate result, you don't ever need to worry about overhead: printing itself is very slow, and you don't want to do it when the result will be more than, say, 1000 lines. But for such harmless amounts of data, performance doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: there is more than performance overhead only. The issue could be with very large inputs, that there will be too much recursion on systems with small stack

Comment: @sehe: ok, I should have made this statement a little less general. Stack size isn't relevant _in this specific case_ since recursive calculation of permutations (assuming the usual algorithm) is `O(n!)` in time, but only `O(n)` in recursion depth. So if you make `n` very large (large enough to be a stack problem), the program would never finish anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it iteratively with `std::next_permutation` from `<algorithm>` as a `while` condition, or depending on how you set up the loop this may be one of the occasions where `do...while` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; // see std::iota also


// important: sort v if not sorted
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()))
{
      // use v (unique permutation)
}
// use v: first sorted position
```